# Android Camera Intent set resolution

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, android-camera-intent

I'm using Android Camera Intent to start a camera capture inside my app

here's my problem ... I need to force the camera to use it's lowest resolution
I already got a list off all possible resolutions

but when I do something like this :

```
Camera c = Camera.open();
Parameters cp = c.getParameters();
List<Size> ls = cp.getSupportedPictureSizes();
cp.setPictureSize(ls.get(0).width, ls.get(0).height);
cp.setPreviewSize(ls.get(0).width, ls.get(0).height);
```

the camera intent opens with an Error dialog saying the camera can not be used.

any help ?

do I need any more permissions other than the use-camera ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

And since you manipulate the camera parameters, you should set the manipulated parameters to the camera like this:

```
c.setParameters(cp);
```

Also be sure that there all camera objects call release() method.

Comment: at SamSung android4.0, when i use c.setParameters(cp);it said no method

Comment: hmmm.. are you sure that the Camera object is the true camera since android have two camera class but in different package. Camera for graphics and Camera for hardware. You must import the Camera for hardware.

See this link:
<http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html>